# Find the integral of $\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\sin^2(x)}$

Tags: integration

Given the integral
$$
\int \frac{\sin(x)}{1+\sin^2(x)}\, dx
$$
I use the substitution $u= \cos x$, then I achieve a new integral of $\int \frac{1}{2-u^2}\, du$. I integrate this using partial fractions as $\int \frac{1}{4(\ln((2+x)/(2-x))}\, dx$, but I get the wrong answer. The limits of integration are $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0$.

Comment: don't forget to accept one of the answers clicking the 'V' in the left side of the answer, and also to vote

Answer (score 2):

> $$\int\frac{\sin x}{1+\sin^2 x}dx$$

$$\color{blue}{\sin^2 x=1-\cos^2 x}$$

$$=\int\frac{\sin x}{2-\cos^2 x}dx$$

Set $t=\cos x$ and $dt=-\sin x dx $

$$-\frac 1 2 \int\frac{dt}{1-t^2/2}$$

Set $\nu =t/\sqrt 2$ and $d\nu=\frac{dt}{\sqrt 2}$

$$=-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\int\frac{1}{1-\nu ^2}d\nu=\dots$$

Answer (score 1):

Just as the other answer but directly, recognizing derivatives of functions and without substitutions:

$$\frac{\sin x}{1+\sin^2x}=\frac{\sin x}{2-\cos^2x}=\frac{\sin x}{2\sqrt2}\left(\frac1{\sqrt2-\cos x}+\frac1{\sqrt2+\cos x}\right)\implies$$

$$\int\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos^2x}dx=\frac1{2\sqrt2}\int\frac{\overbrace{\sin x}^{=(\sqrt2-\cos x)'}}{\sqrt2-\cos x}dx-\frac1{2\sqrt2}\int\frac{\overbrace{-\sin x}^{=(\sqrt2+\cos x)'}}{\sqrt2+\cos x}dx=$$

$$=\color{red}{\frac1{2\sqrt2}\log\frac{\sqrt2-\cos x}{\sqrt2+\cos x}+C}$$